# Maintain UI position with Aspect Ratio Fitter and anchor preset is set to stretch

Tags: unity, gui, aspect-ratio

So i have a text UI using Aspect Ratio Fitter with Aspect Mode Height Control Width and i set anchor preset to stretch upward  .

To make it easier to understand , i want my text to stretch upward only when screen height is increased , and at the same time , using Aspect Ratio Fitter , i want my text to keep width and height aspect ratio by stretching width when height is increased . And don't worry about screen height size become bigger than screen width size because i have separate UI for portrait .

When i apply both anchor preset stretch upward and Aspect Ratio Fitter , UI cannot maintain it position anymore if screen height is increased . **So my question here is straightforward , how do i keep my UI inside my camera view while using Aspect Ratio Fitter and anchor preset is set to stretch ?** , if possible , can it be done using unity built in feature ? (without me writing the script)

Here are screenshot below to show my problem :

(ps : ignore the error it doesn't have any correlation with this problem)

Before screen height change :
[image: Before screen size is changed]

After screen height change  :
[image: After screen height change]

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to use an Aspect Ratio Fitter here. The scaling behaviour you describe sounds more like the match height setting of the canvas scaler's scale with screen size mode.

Comment: @DMGregory oh really ? what was the alternative ?